# How to turn off error messages in Access object using Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm creating an Access object inside Excel VBA error handling code. When an error occurs within a function in Access, I want the error handler to immediately execute, which is currently impeded by the Access VBA runtime error notification. Is there a way to suppress that pop-up window, similar to the function of Excel's "application.displayalerts = false"? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work running from Excel, but inside of Access you can use "DoCmd.SetWarnings False"

Comment: assuming  you have an actual Access object called `myAccess`, try `myAccess.DoCmd.SetWarnings False`